# rereplace on json string with ColdFusion

Tags: json, coldfusion, replace

This does not work. The json is valid.  I would like eventually to replace any `Distributor_ID`: 100 with `Distributor_ID`: 55.  There may be any number of nested items in the json and the path to `Distributor_ID` could vary. If it were deserialized to a structure first, I would have to search for it by path and replace everywhere it was found.  I thought since json is a string, then a simple replace could do it quickly, but I get an error:

```
Invalid token " found.
```

How else to quickly replace a value in serialized json with CF?  Does a quote or apostrophe need to be escaped?

```
<cfset jsonstring= '"SUPPLY": [
{
    "SRole_ID": 1,
    "Distributor_ID": 100,
    "Test": "E974564E-B252-148D-E6FD5EF429885236"
},
{
    "SRole_ID": 1,
    "Distributor_ID": 100,
    "Test": "EC08B56C-95BE-0DCA-DD7789978A05D788"
},
{
    "SRole_ID": 1,
    "Distributor_ID": 13,
    "Test": "EC0BA1FB-F6A7-29E3-CC92FD509BCD487C"
},
{
    "SRole_ID": 1,
    "Distributor_ID": 15,
    "Test": "EC0FEC88-018E-CCEA-668038434E83A4E7"
}
]'>
<cfset newjson =  ReplaceNoCase(jsonstring, 'Distributor_ID": 100', 'Distributor_ID": 50', "ALL")>
<cfdump var="#newjson#">
```

Comment: You've got at least two typos in your code - (`cfeset` instead of `cfset` and one closing `}` too many (right when closing the first cfset)).

Answer (score 6):

Don't use string replacement functions on JSON. JSON is not a string.

JSON is a data structure. Treat it as such.

```
<cfset jsonstring = '{ 
"SUPPLY": [
    {
        "SRole_ID": 1,
        "Distributor_ID": 100,
        "Test": "E974564E-B252-148D-E6FD5EF429885236"
    },
    {
        "SRole_ID": 1,
        "Distributor_ID": 100,
        "Test": "EC08B56C-95BE-0DCA-DD7789978A05D788"
    },
    {
        "SRole_ID": 1,
        "Distributor_ID": 13,
        "Test": "EC0BA1FB-F6A7-29E3-CC92FD509BCD487C"
    },
    {
        "SRole_ID": 1,
        "Distributor_ID": 15,
        "Test": "EC0FEC88-018E-CCEA-668038434E83A4E7"
    }
  ]
}'>

<cfset data = DeserializeJSON(jsonstring)>

<cfloop array="#data.SUPPLY#" index="item">
  <cfset item["Distr"] = item["Distributor_ID"]>
  <cfset StructDelete(item, "Distributor_ID")>
</cfloop>

<cfset newjson = SerializeJSON(data)>
```